# OpenEdge: how to remove HTML tags from a string?

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge, webspeed

I have tried doing this:

```
REPLACE(string, "<*>", "").
```

but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You need to add more information as to what your doing, this is way to little to go on.

Comment: What does this have to do with the `progress` and `openedge` tags?  You tried to use something like REPLACE using what?  A scripting language?  An editor?

Comment: vgoff, Hi. I'm trying to do it in the WebSpeed to be more clear(if you are abot that).
I have a string like "<b>Hello word</b>", and i need to delete 
"<b></b>" part.

Comment: I think you would be better of simply tagging "openedge" and "progress-4gl" in a case like this. It's pretty specific to that platform and the "html" and "tag"-tags are only misleading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REPLACE` doesn't work like that. There's no wildcard matching in it.

I've included a simple way of doing this below. However, there's lots of cases that this wont work in - non well formed html etc. But perhaps you can start here and move forward by yourself.

What I do is look for < and > in the text and replace everything between it with a pipe (|) (you could select any character - preferably something not present in the text. When that's done all pipes are removed.

Again, this is a quick and dirty solution and not safe for production...

```
PROCEDURE cleanHtml:
    DEFINE INPUT  PARAMETER pcString  AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE OUTPUT PARAMETER pcCleaned AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE VARIABLE iHtmlTagBegins AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE iHtmlTagEnds   AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.
    DEFINE VARIABLE lHtmlTagActive AS LOGICAL     NO-UNDO.

    DEFINE VARIABLE i AS INTEGER     NO-UNDO.

    DO i = 1 TO LENGTH(pcString):
        IF lHtmlTagActive = FALSE AND SUBSTRING(pcString, i, 1) = "<" THEN DO:
            iHtmlTagBegins = i.
            lHtmlTagActive = TRUE.
        END.

        IF lHtmlTagActive AND SUBSTRING(pcString, i, 1) = ">" THEN DO:
            iHtmlTagEnds = i.
            lHtmlTagActive = FALSE.

            SUBSTRING(pcString, iHtmlTagBegins, iHtmlTagEnds - iHtmlTagBegins + 1) = FILL("|", iHtmlTagEnds - iHtmlTagBegins).
        END.
    END.

    pcCleaned = REPLACE(pcString, "|", "").

END PROCEDURE.

DEFINE VARIABLE c AS CHARACTER   NO-UNDO.

RUN cleanHtml("This is a <b>text</b> with a <i>little</i> bit of <strong>html</strong> in it!", OUTPUT c).

MESSAGE c VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Comment: Thank you, that works, but only in situations where there is no inner tags (like <b><i>I am bold italic</i></b>, that would print out "<i>I am bold italic</b>"), but i will work towards fixing that.

Comment: Yes, as I said this is pretty schematic solution and not a complete html-parser. Those are a bit more complex.